# Excel shared workbook, resolve conflicts automatic/with vba or just ignore

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to share a workbook on onedrive and allow others to read/write.

The workbook is a fully automated workbook driven by VBA. Nothing is edited manually.
The workbook uses VBA to download data from internet and parses it on to the sheet. It adds one line of data on the last row of one of the sheets.
Other sheets are updated via Excel formulas or pivot tables.

So it's one line at the time that is added. And the data is added once every 10 minutes.

The problem I have is that when my computer adds data to the workbook the other users will get a conflict that Excel can't resolve even though the data is exactly the same.

Is there any way to resolve the conflict automatically, or use a VBA solution or just set it to always ignore since someone else has already saved the same data just prior.

I tried to add a `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before the save but that didn't help.

Any suggestions to suppress the error message that the merge of workbooks was not possible?

EDIT:

The problem can be described as following.
You and me have the file open, it's empty.
You put "A" in A1 and save.
I put "B" in A2 and save.
The merge can be done, no conflict.

You put "A" in A1.
I put "B" in A1.
Conflict, merge is not possible.

The problem I have is:
You put "A" in A1.
I put "A" in A1.
Now there shouldn't be a conflict. But there is by some reason.

The error message is:

[image]

> It can't merge the changes with the changes someone else did to the file.
>   Save as a new copy or ignore my changes (and reopen the file).

EDIT 2
A possible solution would be to refresh the workbook or sheet before you save but as I have understood from googling it's not possible.

Comment: What is the error exactly? And if I understand correctly it is due to Excel trying to parse data to a range that is already filled (in the cloud, not on the local machine) with the exact same data?

Comment: The problem is I have Swedish Excel so I don't exactly know the wording of the error. But it's when Excel tries to save. Excel tries to merge my edits to the file with the other users edits and fails and it becomes a conflict. But **all** values in the complete workbook is exactly the same, that is why I don't understand how it can fail.

Comment: @TimStack I updated the question with the error message. It's not dues to the parsing. The parsing returns the exact same thing independent on what machine you run it on.